# How can I install 13.04 on Nexus 7 instead of 13.10?

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

When I have been installing Ubuntu touch on my Nexus 7 it installs the latest saucy. At the moment there are several things that worked in raring that don't in saucy for the Nexus 7. How can I do a new install on the Nexus 7 but install raring instead of the developing saucy?

Answer (score 1):

The install files you need are available at:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/raring/monthly-06/

These are not currently being regularly updated.

**Note:** *You may be better served by being patient. The current development on **12.10** (saucy) has regressed as they change the underlying OS structure and UI code. Once they fix these issues, you will again be much further ahead than development got to on **12.04** (raring).*

---

Not sure if you can currently use the **phablet-flash** utility to do the install for you.

*Will investigate further ..*